# Как в терминале вывести самую короткую переменную окружения?

Tags: bash, terminal

Добрый вечер. Не подскажете, как в терминале вывести самую короткую переменную окружения?

Comment: Короткую по ключу или по значению?

Comment: Короткую по ключу

Comment: Кому как. Мне проще всего написать на Си


    int 
    main (int ac, char *av[])
    {
      extern char **environ;
      int i, l, imin = 0, lmin = strcspn(environ[0], "=");
    
      for (i = 1; environ[i]; i++) 
        if ((l = strcspn(environ[i], "=")) < lmin) {
          lmin = l;
          imin = i;
        }
        
      *strchr(environ[imin], '=') = 0;
      return puts(environ[imin]) == EOF;
    }

Comment: Спасибо за решение на СИ. Но си еще и компилять нужно, человек явно хотел решение в терминале, на баше.

Comment: Поэтому комментарий, а не ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
set -o posix && set | awk -F= 'NF==2{if (name=="" || length(name)>length($1)) name=$1} END{print name}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
env | awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -n | awk '{$1=""; print $0 }' | head -1
```

Comment: Да, `sort | head` это нетривиальный подход (но практически, видимо, самый правильный, мне как-то в голову не пришел). 

Правда, этот пример не работает (выводит самое короткое `name=value`, а не имя переменной минимальной длины).

--

Работающий пример:

    env | tr '=' ' ' | awk '{print $1}' | sort | head -1

Answer (score 1):

Работает только в bash, не в sh. Зато без awk =)

```
for i in `env`; do
    key=${i%=*}
    [[ -z $short_env ]] && short_env=$key;
    [[ ${#key} -lt ${#short_env} ]] && short_env=$key;
done

echo "Shortest env variable: $short_env"
```

Answer (score 0):

Питон входит в состав почти любого дистрибутива. Можно попробовать решить задачу на Питоне. Например, так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf-8

import os

minlen = 100000 # берем большое значение "от балды"

for var in os.environ:
    if (var == '_'):
      # Переменная окружения "_" -- это имя (этой) программы.
      # Поэтому проигнорируем
      pass
    else:
      varlen = len(var)  # длина ключа
      if (varlen < minlen):
        minlen = varlen  # новая длина ключа
        minvar = var     # новая переменная с минимальной длиной ключа

print minvar, "=", os.environ[minvar]
```

Не претендую на идеальность самого решения, но предлагаю как вариант направление решения задачи на Питоне.

В результате работы программы на консоль будет выведена первая минимальная по длине ключа переменная, а также ее значение. Следует заметить, что в переменных окружения могут присутствовать и другие переменные с такой же длиной ключа.

Прога написана в контексте Python ver.2x.